# How remove elements in array with out messing with the counter or list length

Tags: python

Codewars: Given a list **lst** and a number **N,** create a new list that contains each number of **lst** at most **N** times without reordering. For example if N = 2, and the input is [1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3], you take [1,2,3,1,2], drop the next [1,2] since this would lead to 1 and 2 being in the result 3 times, and then take 3, which leads to [1,2,3,1,2,3].

```
delete_nth ([1,1,1,1],2) # return [1,1]
  
delete_nth ([20,37,20,21],1) # return [20,37,21]
```

I'll loop through the array to find the elements that have more than "x" amount. But The problem for me is that when I want to remove that element it changes the length of the array there for throwing off my loop counter. And then when I try another way by creating another list and then again looping through the original list and seeing if the element has more than "x" amount then I'll copy that element into the new array leaving the old array alone and it keeping its index and the loop is fine but now I do not know how to stop copying the element once it hits its desired amount. Please help me. I have been on this answer for a week now.

Comment: Think to use `Counter` from collections.

Comment: I agree that `collections.Counter` is what you want here, but in general when mutating lists as you iterate, it can be useful to iterate backwards, or else to use both a read-iterator and a write-iterator (this last not directly representable in Python; you have to use an index for that)

Comment: Instead of deleting an list element, you can instead replace it with None. Or keep a side list of indicies you want to delete, and when you're done iterating, use the side list to delete everything you wanted to delete.

Comment: Another approach is to use a `while` loop and manually increment the index but only in iterations where you do not delete the current element. (Then again, this is the destructive approach; the task requires a non-destructive approach, where you have to "create a new list", so no deleting should take place.)

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. I am going to look into everyone one of these! You all helped tons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this snippet to see that helps?

Have not done too many edge cases - so please raise questions, if run into some edges.

```
def delete_nth(lst, N):
    
    seen = {}
    res = []
    
    for x in lst:
      if x not in seen :
        seen[x] = 0
      else:
        seen[x] += 1
        
      if seen[x] <N:
        res.append(x)
    return res

print(delete_nth([1, 1, 1, 1], 2))      # [1, 1]
print(delete_nth([20, 37, 20, 22], 1))  # [20, 37, 22]
```

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thank you so much. Now I am going to study and read it until I understand why and how it works. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad it helps. Just try to run some more inputs in https://pythontutor.com/ to visually inspect each steps.

Comment: Good. You can increase the readability by either replacing `seen = {}` with `seen = collections.defaultdict(int)`, in which your `if` is replaced by simply `seen[x] += 1`, or you can leave `seen = {}` and replace the `if` with `seen.setdefault(x, 0); seen[x] += 1`; but that's just cosmetics.

Comment: Wow, thanks again that is going to actually help tons. I didn't even know this was a thing. You helped tons.

Comment: @Amadan - Agreed.  But to make it simpler for OP to digest is the primary goal here. ;-).  Thanks for the comments.